# How to filter/remove columns in Tableau when there is no data

Tags: tableau-desktop

Trying to create a longish timeseries of trends in A-level results over past three years.

It looks like this:

[image]

Two problems. I can't find any options to remove the columns in visualisation where there is no data such as 2019 or 2023.

And how I squeeze the padding so the data is more scrollable?

https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/elksie5000/viz/TopAgradesatA-levelin2022/Dashboard1?publish=yes

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just changed the data type of "Year" into date and dragged it to the columns pane. now the values range between 2020 to 2022

[image: like this]

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: tried a different approach